# Viewing pipeline technical example

Tags: java, math, graphics, 3d

### What I'm trying to do in a sentence

I'm trying to implement a viewing pipeline in Java by myself, so I'm using only Java AWT to draw 2D Polygons on canvas, without the help of OpenGL at all.

### Purpose of this post

I'd like to test my results with you, since it's a difficult topic and I might have misunderstood some points.

### So let's describe my setup...

I have made some raw data files for testing. Here's a file which represent a 3D Cube:

```
8 // number of vertices
0 0 0 // list of vertices indices...
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
12 // number of polygons
0 1 // first polygon coordinates indices (so the first polygon is 0 0 0 to 1 0 0)
1 2 // second polygon is 1 0 0 
2 3 // and so on
3 0
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 0
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

The above are actually 12 polylines which should form the 3D cube on screen.

Here's the camera configuration:

```
Position 0.5 0.5 1 // position of camera
LookAt 0.5 0.5 0.5 // look at point
Up 0 1 0 // up vector
Window -1 1 -1 1 // window size, (-1,-1) to (1,1) includes all the above polygons in window
Viewport 800 600 // viewport size, not so relevant
```

### What I expect to happen

When I draw the above polygons, since my camera looks at the center of the cube, and positioned exactly in front of it (from a distance of 1 so I'll be able to see something),
**I expect to see just a normal square on the screen (because all the 3D edges would be exactly behind the square face).**

### What actually happens

[image]

### How I approached in order to solve the problem...

I dived into my code in order to figure out where the diagonals are from, and realized that although I'd expect the coordinates (0,0,0) and (0,0,1) to fall on the same spot in 2D (in particular when we are perpendicular with the cube exactly), they are diagonal to each other.

More detailed:

Transforming the (0,0,0) coordinate to view coordinate results in (-0.5,-0.5,-1) while the (0,0,1) is transformed to (-0.5,-0.5,0).

Now, when projecting each one to 2D, the (0,0,0) becomes (0.5,0.5) and the (0,0,1) becomes (-0.5,-0.5). That's why they appear diagonal, and drawing the polygon 0 4 (basically a line between them) is a diagonal line.

### What I actually need to figure out

**Why is this happening?**

**Am I wrong about my assumption that I should see a square, or I'm all good and it's probably a bug in the calculations? Do you get the same result as mine?**

In case anyone was wondering, here are the calculations I've used to transform into viewing coordinates:

[image]

And to project on 2D space:

[image]

I calculated d as if it was the distance from the camera to the lookat point, but in seond mind I might be wrong. Here's my source (which I think I misunderstood but can't figure out what is d):

[image]

### Edit:

According to Nico's answer, now I set d = 1 (and left the equation with /z+d, yet). I also changed 8th polygon from 7 0 to 7 4 which makes more sense. This is what I get, the numbers are the changes in camera position:

[image]

Why the diagonals on z=1 appear like that?

Comment: What value of `d` are you using (and why)? To me, this looks like you actually put your projection center somewhere inside of the cube, and you naturally get the points "behind" projected mirrored in front of it. Also, your formulas seem to to really match well, because the view matrix transforms to an eye space where the camera is at origin, but your projection puts the center somewhere else at distance `d`.

Comment: well, I thought d was the distance from the camera point to the lookat point. 
re-looking at this I might be wrong... I've edited the question regarding what d I use, maybe that's the problem..!

Comment: I guess x,y,z is the camera position so it shouldnt be it but "center of projection" to some point on the plane. What is the center of projection and to what point on the plane do i calculate the distance with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your center of projection is in the back face of the cube. Therefore, points on this face are projected into infinity. Move the center of projection a bit further (e.g. set z-coordinate to 2).

Secondly, your view transform and projection transform seem to not match. Use the following transform to get reasonable values:

```
xp = d * x / z
yp = d * y / z
zp = d
```

Usually, `d` is set to 1, but it does not really matter if you set a reasonable window size.

Remember that this is a perspective transform. Therefore, the points `(0, 0, 0)` and `(0, 0, 1)` will not project onto the same point.

Comment: 1. How do I move the "center of projection" to 2? What is it exactly?
2. Where are those formulas from? Why is it different than what I gave?
3. How do I exactly calculate d?

Comment: Also do you realize that / z is not possible? What if z == 0? Another proof it should be + d...

Comment: Ok I tested your equations, and when z was 0 I simple used xp=x and yp=y. (I omit z entirely as I do not do culling). I get exactly the same result. But when I position the camera in 0.5,0.5,2 instead of 1, I get this:http://i63.tinypic.com/okre3p.png

Comment: P.S read in CG's book by Donald Heaper that the equation should be /z+d and not /z

Comment: Except from the right diagonal, the image is now correct. Division by zero happens when the point is in the same projection plane as the projection center (camera). Those points do not have an image. If you want to divide by `z+d`, you have to subtract `d` from the projection center in the view matrix.

Comment: Are you sure? The book & the course material doesn't mention that. They show the view transformation & the projection calculation just as I did...

Comment: Anyway, I updated the question with some new picture, for / z + d and d=1. Btw you didn't explain me why set d to 1, is it permanent or I could somehow calculate it?
P.S I fixed the 8th polygon, from 7 0 which caused the diagonal, to 7 4 which makes more sense

Comment: `d` is just the distance of the virtual projection plane to the camera. When `d` gets larger, everything is scaled up. And since you do another scaling afterwards to adapt to the viewport, is it common to set `d` to some arbitrary value (mostly 1), which simplifies calculations. There is a discrepancy in the coordinate systems of your equations. The view transform places the origin at the projection center, whereas the projection assumes it to be on the projection plane. That's why I made this correction. You can check the math yourself. It's simple application of intercept theorem.

Comment: Unless `P` is not supposed to be the projection center. But that's what I assumed.

Comment: Ok, my bad. P is the position of the camera, L is the lookAt point, V is the up vector. So now what is the correct way?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. The correct way is what I described (divide by `z`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110640/discussion-between-jjang-and-nico-schertler).

Comment: I have a continuation to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038745/computer-graphics-implementing-viewing-pipeline