# Computer Graphics implementing Viewing Pipeline

Tags: java, opengl, math, graphics, 3d

This is a continuation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901491/viewing-pipeline-technical-example/36907936#36907936).

### In a nutshell

I'm implementing viewing pipeline using Java AWT, imitating the behaviour of OpenGL (without using it of course).

### Changes from the older question

I've changed projection to Orthographic instead of Perspective (so the transformation is just removing the z-index now, keeping x,y the same).

Changes to input files:

Cube file (notice it contains 6 faces of the cube now instead 12 polylines like before, but it doesn't actually change anything)

```
8 // number of vertices
0 0 0 // list of vertices indices...
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
12 // number of polygons
0 1 2 3// first polygon coordinates indices (so the first polygon is 0 0 0, 1 0 0, 1 1 0, 0 1 0)
4 5 6 7 // second polygon vertices indices
1 2 6 5 // and so on
0 3 7 4
2 3 7 6
0 1 5 4
```

New camera configuration (changed position of camera):

```
Position 0.7 0.7 2 // position of camera
LookAt 0.5 0.5 0.5 // look at point
Up 0 1 0 // up vector
Window -1 1 -1 1 // window size, (-1,-1) to (1,1) includes all the above polygons in window
Viewport 800 600 // viewport size, not so relevant
```

The idea was to move the camera abit in the up-right direction, and take a "step back" (z=2), to see the depth of the cube (because if camera was positioned in 0.5,0.5,Z then I wouldn't have seen depth).

**I'd expect the cube to appear 'perfect' now, such that each of its' edges would be equal.
However, this is what I get:**

[image]

As you see, the closer and farther faces of the cubes (the ones initiated from the first and second polygons actually) are indeed in the same dimensions, but the other faces are thinner for some reason.

I suspect that for some reason, the x,y values of coordinates becomes way far from each other than the z coordinates.
This actually makes sense, since in the Viewport Transformation scales only the x,y values (since we're already in 2D), but I'd expect that the cube would look different as I said above...

Any ideas?

#### Edit

Adding matrices and calculations since I probably have bug in the pipeline.

Note window is now (-3,-3) to (3,3) and camera position is (2,2,2).

```
World-View matrix
0.7071    0.0000   -0.7071   -2.0000 
-0.4082    0.8165   -0.4082   -2.0000 
0.5774    0.5774    0.5774   -2.0000 
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000 

Projection matrix
1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 
0.0000    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000 
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000 

Viewport matrix
133.3333    0.0000    0.0000  156.3333 
0.0000  100.0000    0.0000  123.0000 
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
```

#### Another edit

Thanks to Nico's comment I've was multiplying in world-view matrix in the wrong order, after fixing this bug the new matrix is:

```
World-View matrix
0.7071    0.0000   -0.7071    0.0000
-0.4082    0.8165   -0.4082    0.0000
0.5774    0.5774    0.5774   -1.7321
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
```

Comment: Hint: Do they look even thinner if you move the camera to `0.6 0.6 2`? How about `2 2 2`?

Comment: first one: yes, they're thinner. second one: they're out of the viewport... (window is from -1,-1 to 1,1). Why? can you be more explicit?

Comment: Because that's how 3D works. Go and grab a cardboard box, and sit it a few meters away from you (to minimize the effects of perspective). Position your head so it almost lines up with the middle of the side of the box that's facing you. Can't see the other sides, right? Now move slightly up and right (to 0.6 0.6). Now you can only slightly see the other sides. And the further you move your head away from that middle position, the "thicker" the other sides appear to be.

Comment: As immibis already explained, your result looks correct (although I don't agree completely with his explanation). If you want all sides to have equal length, you need an isometric projection. Move your camera to `(2 2 2)` to get an isometric projection. If parts of the cube are outside of the viewport (two corners should be exactly in the center), just increase the window size.

Comment: @NicoSchertler in (2 2 2) I do not see anything... all coordinats hit outside of viewport. Dont forget my cube is from 0,0,0 to 1,1,1 - so when applying world-view transformation, I translate by camera position * -1, so all points hit outside (most upper right point is 1 1 1, so its x,y becomes -2 -2 z).

Comment: Also, I thought enlarging the view to (-3,-3) (3,3) would help, but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. How come?

Comment: Then there is a bug somewhere. According to the formulas in your other question, the view transform should be `{{0.707107, 0., -0.707107, 0.}, {-0.408248, 0.816497, -0.408248, 
  0.}, {0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735, -3.4641}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}`. Transforming the corner `{1, 1, 1, 1}` with the view transform should yield `{0, 0, -1.73205, 1}`, which is centered in the viewport and `1.73205` units away from the camera.

Comment: Might have found something.
When I pre-calculate the world-view matrix (and actually also the rest of the matrices), I multiply the transformation matrices before multiplying with the point (as a vector).
Thought it was ok, but...
When I think of it, in the idea of "transforming and then rotating/scaling", there's importance to the order of multiplication. If I translate the point and then rotate it (as should be) then it's diffrerent from multiplying the rotation matrix with the translation matrix and THEN multiplying with point,since + and * order is changed. Am i right?

Comment: Because the rotation is actually to multiply the point, and the translation is adding / substracting some value to it. So the order of this operations matter...

Comment: It should not be different. You are right that transform order matters. If you multiply `rotation_matrix * translation_matrix` and use this to transform the vector `v`, it is equivalent to `rotate(translate(v))`. You can see that by putting parentheses around `translation_matrix * v`.

Comment: Let me edit and post the matrices. This way we'll see in what stage I have a bug, and then you can write a more official answer... :)

Comment: Your view transform is wrong. Apparently, you switched the matrix order. Last column should be `(0 0 -3.464 1)`.

Comment: You're indeed right, I switched the order and it looks fantastic. Could you please check the rest of the matrices so I will be sure there are no more bugs?

Comment: Yes, the other matrices are correct. If you want to get a real cube, you should incorporate the viewport's aspect ratio in the projection matrix.

Comment: Ok. And one last thing. Why do I see exactly the same result with camera position (1,1,1) and (2,2,2)?

Comment: Because it's an orthographic projection ;). The view directions are exactly the same for the two camera positions (one is just a bit further than the other). And since it is no perspective projection, the scene won't scale with depth.

Comment: Woah :) Please write an answer so I can at least accept something after all this effort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an orthographic projection, the thickness of the faces depends on the view angle. When you look directly at a face, the thickness of adjacent faces becomes zero. Whereas, when you look directly at a corner of the cube (i.e. isometric projection), all faces will have equal size.

Here are some sample views that visualize this behavior:

[image: 0°]
[image: 11.25°]
[image: 22.5°]
[image: 33.75°]
[image: 45° - isometry]